# How can I check out my app working in countries where google services are not allowed?

Tags: android, server, google-play-services

I'm developing the application that depends on Play Market and App store (subscription has to be paid). I want to check how does that subsription works in countries where Google services are switched off (China, Cuba, Crimea in Russia and so on). The only idea is to buy the VDS server in every country of that list, but maybe there are any other ways to solve my problem?